# .htaccess -> RewriteRule, subdomains -> stop redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want add to my website subdomains.

I have one file with that format:

```
starwines.com.pl / test.php? page = first
starwines.com.pl / test.php? page = second
starwines.com.pl / test.php? page = third
...
```

subdomains how i want to have:

```
first.starwines.com.pl
second.starwines.com.pl
third.starwines.com.pl
...
```

.htaccess ->
I did something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^first.starwines.com.pl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.first.starwines.com.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://starwines.com.pl/test.php?page=first [R=301,L]
```

This code almost works, but the URL changes to the file `test.php`
I want subdomains that stay unchanged: `test.starwines.com`

Please help me :(

Comment: What do you think `R=301` means?

Comment: Why do you specify `http://starwines.com.pl` ?

Comment: Code that I use I found on the web :/ When I removed `R=301`, problem persisted

Comment: After you removed `R` it still persists because you're specifying full url with another hostname. Programming is when you understand what you do, not blindly copy-paste something "found on the web"

Comment: Ouu... :) Thank you very much for your help -> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?page=first [L]`

Comment: Last question... what am I doing wrong here? -> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).starwines.com.pl$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: guys ? Have u any advice ?

Comment: what am I doing wrong here? -> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).starwines.com.pl$` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: 1. ask a separate question 2. "what am I doing wrong here" is a terrible question - we have no idea what is your aim.

Comment: Sorry! This is because I'm weak in English :) ok, I assume a new question :)